# Why does assignment to python type 'list' work?

Tags: python, list

In Python, I noticed my brother was assigning lists using the *'list'* function, which I told him was wrong to do as you should always create a variable. The problem is, his code was working, and I don't know why?

eg:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
a = list
print(a)
```

Why does this work?

Also, can someone explain to me why if I create two variables referencing *list*, and modify one, the other variable gets modified too? Is this a reference to an object in memory? What is a use for this?
eg:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
a = list
b = list
b.pop(0)
print(a, b)
```

Outputs:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5] [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I cant seem to find any documentation on this specific case, so I thought I would ask everyone here :) Thanks

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html would be a great read to start understanding how Python deals with names and values.

Comment: You are not assigning to the `list` function, but to some name that just happended to be bound to the `list` function before that assignment. It does not change the behaviour of `list` in other modules or the way list comprehension etc. work. Anyway, don't do that.

Comment: You do understand that, if you just say `list`, without parens, it's not creating anything, it's just a reference to the `list` constructor, right? Assigning to `list` will make `list()` break (because you've name shadowed the `list` constructor, and now `list` just points to some arbitrary instance of a `list`), but it doesn't change Python's aliasing rules at all.